# Xcode 9: Curious Custom Font Behavior

Tags: xcode, fonts

I'm getting some odd behavior with an installed custom font. I've installed the font using all the steps outlined by various articles (many, many times). When I use the font, however, the rendering seems to use the default for the family, rather than the specific font style I am trying to use. To be specific, the font renders as Didot, but is not bold and/or italicized, which is the expected behavior.

Including some screenshots of the font itself, and the various install points to ensure all is good there.

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this behavior?

[The font as shown when selected in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTaXz.png)

[Font in plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3dJH.png)

[Font in resource bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q04om.png)

[Output of installed fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztszh.png)

[Selecting font in storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJKvs.png)

[Font as rendered in storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J74lZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer I received on Apple's dev forums. I'm going to mark it as correct. I will update this thread if I find it is not the case, but I believe it's on the proper path for resolution.

> It sort of looks like you have conflicting definitions of how the styles and weights are arranged in the Didot family, possibly because this Didot Bold Italic font came from a different foundry, or is in an older font file format, or it conflicts with an existing font's relationship to the family.
>
> You're probably not going to get any more clarification here, because the problem is probably not in Xcode or the frameworks, but in the font files themselves.